# Finding i values where Y = a number

Tags: r

I'm a student just learning how to use R and thus far I've made a bit of progress.  I'm snagging at a question which asks:  For what values of i does Y equal 3?

the data set:  c(3,5,2,3,5,4,4,2,3,5)

Comment: Type in `?Syntax` for a list of basic operators. The links on that page under "See Also" will tell you more...If that somehow doesn't work, this is an online mirror of that page: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the index, `i` inside the data set (in this case, a vector) `Y` such that `Y[i]=3`?

Then you just need to use the `which` function. For more information, make sure you try reading the help files, which you can invoke using the command `?which` or `help(which)`

Now, some code:

```
# Your data
Y <-  c(3,5,2,3,5,4,4,2,3,5)

# Find the index where Y is equal to 3
which(Y==3, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

And welcome to SO. This is a pretty common question for beginners, so next time, make sure you Google or search around for a solution to elementary problems such as these. Have a good day.

Comment: `which(Y==3)` should suffice, not need to use `arr.ind` argument ;)

Comment: @Jilber Yes, you are correct. I don't know why, but I always include the `arr.ind` argument when I use the `which` function. I guess it became a habit.

Comment: From documentation you can learn why and when to use `arr.ind`. `should array indices be returned when x is an array?` so it is useful when dealing with arrays, when using `which` with a vector it will always return the index meeting the condition.